# Problem with DataBindings, explain please

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass("one", "two");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", myClass, "Text1", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", myClass, "Text2", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
    }

    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myClass.Text1 = textBox1.Text;
        myClass.Text2 = textBox2.Text;
        //textBox1.DataBindings["Text"].WriteValue();
        //textBox2.DataBindings["Text"].WriteValue();
    }
}

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Text1;
    private string _Text2;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Text1
    {
        get { return _Text1; }
        set { _Text1 = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text1")); }
    }

    public string Text2
    {
        get { return _Text2; }
        set { _Text2 = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text2")); }
    }

    public MyClass(string text1, string text2)
    {
        Text1 = text1;
        Text2 = text2;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

I think is pretty clear what I'm trying to achieve. I want my form to save the changes made in my two `TextBox`es to `myClass`. But whenever I press the save button after editing both text boxes, and `saveButton_Click` is invoked, the second `textBox2`'s `Text` goes back to the original text ("two"). I tried using `Binding`'s `WriteValue` function but the same thing happens. Using .net 4.0.

**Edit** Thanks for your answers, but I don't need workarounds. I can find them myself. I just need to understand a little bit better how binding works. I would like to understand why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, updating any value on the data source will cause all bindings to be updated.  This explains the behavior (setting `myClass.Text1` causes `textBox2` to be updated with the current value of `myClass.Text2`).  Unfortunately, the few posts I was able to find pretty much just said, "that's how it works".

One way to handle this is to create a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158145.aspx), set `BindingSource.DataSource = myClass`, and then bind your TextBoxes to the `BindingSource`.

`BindingSource` raises [ListChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.listchanged.aspx) events if the underlying data source is a list and items are added, removed, etc., *or* if the `DataSource` properties change.  You can suppress these events by setting [BindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.raiselistchangedevents.aspx) to `false`, which would let you set multiple properties on `myClass` without data-binding updating the bound controls.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass("one", "two");
    BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bindingSource.DataSource = myClass;

        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, "Text1", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, "Text2", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);                
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
        myClass.Text1 = textBox1.Text;
        myClass.Text2 = textBox2.Text;
        bindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: That worked. But I don't understand why if my properties are not part of a list.

Comment: @jsoldi, I edited my answer to include the fact that `ListChanged` is also raised when the `DataSource` properties change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the way you are doing your data binding. Try this.

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass("one", "two");

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", myClass, "Text1", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", myClass, "Text2", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}

private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your object should already have new text values entered.
    // Save your object!

    //myClass.Text1 = textBox1.Text;
    //myClass.Text2 = textBox2.Text;
    //textBox1.DataBindings["Text"].WriteValue();
    //textBox2.DataBindings["Text"].WriteValue();
}
```

The key is the DataSourceUpdateMode, this will allow the text property of the textbox to cascade into your custom object whenever the property changes. I hope this helps.

**[Edit]**

I believe what you need to do to achieve what you're asking for is this:
`TextBox1.DataBindings[0].ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never`
This [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/23b15033-defd-44ab-842c-6d9a76661202) should provide some additional information.

Comment: But I don't want the data to be saved when the `TextBox`'s `Text` changes, I want it to change when the save Button is pressed. How can I do that? Isn't `DataSourceUpdateMode.Never` together with `WriteValue()` intended to achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: Don't use databindings. Just manually assign the text values in the forms constructor to the textboxes, like this: `textBox1.Text = myClass.Text1;`

Comment: @jsoldi - then don't use data binding for those values - set the values in the saveButton_Click event. That is what databinding is for - it binds the properties of the control instances to the properties of the data object.

Comment: I tried that. But I want that if I have to windows editing the same `MyClass` object and one saves changes, the other automatically updates. I can find a workaround, like saving `textBox2.Text` in a temporary string and then assign it in the `saveButton_Click` but my question really is why is this happening? Is it __supposed__ to be that way?

Comment: Yes that is the way data-binding works out of the box. Take a look at my last edit, this should achieve what you're after.