# C# DataBinding - What part of "Never" doesn't .Net understand?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

So frankly I don't see any fix for this because it's .Net's screw up, but perhaps others have seen this behavior and know a better workaround.

I basically wanted to create a way to preserve window settings between application executions, and so I naturally used the Settings system.  Now, tragically, the `WindowState` does not have an event that triggers when it changes so we have to be a little creative when the `ClientSize` changes, but all in all not to difficult to track.  However, on start up there is one simple problem:

```
this.DataBindings.Add(
    new Binding(nameof(this.Location), 
    Properties.Settings.Default, 
    nameof(Properties.Settings.Default.MainLoc), 
    true, 
    DataSourceUpdateMode.Never) 
    { 
        ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never 
    });
this.DataBindings.Add(
    new Binding(nameof(this.ClientSize), 
    Properties.Settings.Default, 
    nameof(Properties.Settings.Default.MainSize), 
    true, 
    DataSourceUpdateMode.Never) { 
        ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never 
    });
this.DataBindings.Add(
    new Binding(nameof(this.WindowState), 
    Properties.Settings.Default, 
    nameof(Properties.Settings.Default.MainState), 
    true, 
    DataSourceUpdateMode.Never) { 
        ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never 
    });
```

`DataSourceUpdateMode.Never`. HA. What a joke. Put a break point at that code, and then put a breakpoint in the `Properties.Settings.Default.Main` properties on the Settings class.  Every time I run this, the moment I add these bindings, they WRITE to the datasource completely ignoring the fact that I told these bindings SPECIFICALLY to NEVER update the datasource.  That seems like an extremely bad design.

Does anyone know of ANY way to add a databinding like this where it truly NEVER updates the control or the data source, unless I specifically call `Binding.ReadValue` or `Binding.WriteValue`?

Comment: binding mode = OneWay would seem to be more effective or UpdateSourceTrigger=Manual

Comment: Agree it gives us less choice. Alternative is to use a `BindingSource` which is more powerful. See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045921. Use `bindingSource.SuspendBinding()` call before binding. And resume binding later when you need the data. No need of `ReadValue` and `WriteValue`.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.datasourceupdatemode(v=vs.110).aspx

Remarks
Note that even if this property is set to Never, the binding will update at least one time, when it is first established.